# Xamarin Android Auth0 WCF how to setup

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android, auth0

I am trying to write an app with WCF as back end service and using Xamarin. I want to use token based authentication and i am evaluating https://auth0.com. I succeded in getting the token from auth0 in my Xamarin android app. Also looking at the [tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native-mobile/xamarin/wcf-api) I can setup the WCF web service. I am stuck at understanding how the whole thing works together? How do i use the Auth0 token received to communicate with my WCF service? Or rather how does the server know that it is the authenticated user from the token? How to use the token in my app when accessing the web service. Any one has similar arrangement before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have done everything mentioned [here](https://auth0.com/docs/wcf-tutorial) to setup your behavior on your services then you should be able to add the token to the request header.

If you are using the webhttpbinding like they suggest then you should be able to intercept the message in a BeforeSendRequest

```
var header = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
header.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token);

request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, header);
```

or if you are using WCF with soap and a wsHttpBinding or similar then you can

```
((HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]).Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token);
```

Once the behavior is on your WCF service  it will authenticate the token for every call made to a service that has that behavior attached to it. You can add a breakpoint in ValidateJsonWebToken.cs (which installed as part of the NuGet package from auth0) to see where it authenticates.

Comment: So am i right in saying My App -> Auth0 -> Token ->My App-> WCF Call w ith Token -> WCF Server -> Auth0 to validate token? Or basically given a token and of course the setup for auth0 in server side, the WCF server can validate it?

Comment: @asb yes that is how it works. So if your services aren't setup correctly with the behavior you will be under the false assumption that they are authenticated.

Comment: finally.. request.AddHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth0User.IdToken) did the trick (using restsharp) :)